# How to parallelize operations on a huge array

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I couldn't find any relevant topics so I'm posting this one:

How can I parallelize operations/calculations on a huge array? The problem is that I use the arrays with size of 10000000x10 which is basically small enough to operate on in line, but while running on parfor - causes not enough memory error.

The code goes:

```
function aggregatedRes = umbrellaFct(preparedInputsAsaCellArray)

% Description: function used to parallelize calculation 
% preparedInputsAsaCellArray - cell array with size of 1x10, for example first
% cell {1,1} would be: {array,corr,df}
% array - an array 1e7 by 10, with data from different regions to be aggregated 
% corr - correlation matrix 
% df - degrees of freedom as an integer value 

% create a function handle from child function 
fcnHndl = @childFct;

% For each available cell - calculate and aggregate
parfor j = 1:numel(preparedInputsAsaCellArray)
    output = fcnHndl(preparedInputsAsaCellArray{j}{:});
end

% Extract results 
for i = 1:numel(preparedInputsAsaCellArray)
    aggregatedRes(:,i) = output{j};
end
end
```

And child function used in the umberella function:

```
function aggregated = childFct(array, corr, df)
% Description: 
% array - an array 1e7 by 10, with data from different regions to be aggregated 
% corr - correlation matrix 
% df - degrees of freedom as an integer value 

% get num of cases for multivariate nums
cases = lenght(array(:,1));

% preallocate space 
corrMatrix = double(zeros(cases, size(corr,1)))
u = corrMatrix; 
soerted = corrMatrix;
s = zeros(lenght(array(:,1)), lenght(array(1,:)));

% calc multivariate nums
u = mvtrnd(corr, df, cases);

clear corr, cases

% calc t-students cumulative dist 
u = tcdf(u, df);

clear df

% double sort 
[~, sorted] = sort(u);
clear u 
[~, corrMatrix] = sort(sorted);
clear sorted 

for jj = 1:lenght(lossData(1,:))
    s(:,jj) = array(corrMatrix(:,jj),jj);
end

clear array corrMatrix jj

aggregated = sum(s,2);
end
```

I already tried with distributed memory but ultimately failed.
I will apreciate any help or hint!

Edit: The logic behind functions is to calculate and aggregate data from different regions. In total there are ten arrays, all with size 1e7x10. My idea was to use parfor to simultaneously calculate and aggregate them - to save time. It works fine for smaller arrays (like 1e6x10) but runned out of memory for 1e7x10 (in case of more than 2 pools). I suspect the way i used and implemented parfor could be wrong and inefficient.

Comment: When getting "out of memory" type of error, here are my steps of thinking: 1) Are you able to avoid memory issue in other comparable tasks operating on similar data size? 2) What is the apparent upper bound before you run into memory issue on the current task? Is it comparable to the desired data size? 3) From 1) & 2), you should be able to conclude whether you can a) split your data into sub blocks and process block-by-block or b) upgrade your system and expect to be able to solve the issue. Your case looks like neither though. It looks like you are not using `parfor` the way it is intended.

Comment: On the communication front, in my opinion, a question like how to parallelize an **unspecified** operation should be closed for lack of focus. Meanwhile, you seem to have something more specific, but your question makes no direct mention of it. Maybe describe a little what the operation is? Characterize a little with words? -- code does not replace English. Perhaps some comments in-line?

Comment: Thank you @Argyll for reply, I already added description.